# How to get the defaults from java.util.Properties

Tags: java, properties

A `Properties` object contains a map of key-value pairs and additionally a "defaults" `Properties` field that is **protected**.

One can iterate over the keys via `keySet()` to get the property keys of the current `Properties`, and also via `stringPropertyNames()` to get all distinct keys including the keys within the "defaults" `Properties`.

I would like to write a method that, given a `Properties` instance, returns these "defaults", including the keys and values.

Iterating the `stringPropertyNames()` and skipping values that are included in `keySet()` is not sufficient, since the entries in the "defaults" may be hidden by entries in the current `Properties`. Accessing the **protected** "defaults" field via reflection will show a warning output and may not work in future java versions.

Comment: Indeed Properties lacks appropriate ways to do such things. E.g. to just get the true size (the number of keys for which values are defined) you cannot use `size()` but need to call `stringPropertyNames().size()` what internally creates a new `HashMap` and collects all values just to count the keys and throw the map into the garbage collector what is totally inefficient but the API prevents to solve such things efficiently. To get the defaults the answer may be the best option but it will return a copy that does not reflect later changes to the default instance.

Answer (score 1):

The `Properties.clone()` method will create a new `Properties` object including the defaults. This clone can be emptied and what's left are the "defaults":

```
public static Properties getDefaultProperties(final Properties properties) {
    // use a clone to not modify the supplied properties
    final Properties clone = (Properties) properties.clone();
    // since we cannot access the default properties, we simply remove all non-default
    clone.clear();
    // what remains are the default properties that we will copy
    final Properties defaultProperties = new Properties();
    for (final String property : clone.stringPropertyNames()) {
        defaultProperties.setProperty(property, clone.getProperty(property));
    }
    return defaultProperties;
}
```